# Google Nearby Connections - no data transfer with Wifi

Tags: android, google-nearby

I have the following setup: a Motorola G4 and a G5, one as advertiser, the other one in discovery. The strategy is star. Nearby tries to create the connection over Wifi, but the connection either a) doesn't even get created or b) when one device is connected to the hotspot of the other, no data is transferred.
Using the cluster strategy (Bluetooth only) works fine though.

Since I'd like to use the Wifi connection because of its higher bandwidth - does anyone know how to tackle this problem?

I can also provide logs, but they are pretty long and I'm not sure what of them is of help.

Google Play Services version is 12.2.21 on both devices.